# Python Pandas Dataframe - remove data from dataframe if indexed date is older than a certain date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df) which is indexed by date

```
date             BBG.XSWX.KABN.S  BBG.XETR.TKA.S                        
2014-02-03       328.657522          19.083
2014-02-04       327.776510          18.809
2014-02-05       325.657202          18.337
2014-02-06       330.845170          18.690
2014-02-07       334.789668          19.153
```

Is there a way to remove any rows that have an indexed date which is older than say 2014-02-06, so I would have the resulting dataframe:

```
date             BBG.XSWX.KABN.S  BBG.XETR.TKA.S                       
2014-02-06       330.845170          18.690
2014-02-07       334.789668          19.153
```

Comment: the edits made by @users4393829 don't correct what is perfectly correct code by the OP i.e. the index (here 'date') can correctly be one level down!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you might want to try :

```
df.loc[df.index < '2014-02-06']
```

if your index is in datetime format then

```
df.loc[df.index < pd.to_datetime('2014-02-06')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas does allow row slicing:

```
>>> df['2014-02-06':]
            BBG.XSWX.KABN.S  BBG.XETR.TKA.S
date                                       
2014-02-06       330.845170          18.690
2014-02-07       334.789668          19.153
```